# Optimization problem

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-optimization

Any hints on how to solve this problem? 
\begin{align}\label{eq:opt}
\max_{\beta_i} \quad &  \alpha_0 \log_2 \left(1+ \sum_{i=1}^{N}\lambda_i^2\beta_i  \right) + (1- \alpha_0) \log_2 \left(1 + \Big(\sum_{i=1}^{N} \xi_i\sqrt{\beta_i} \Big)^2 \right)  \cr
{{\rm s}.{\rm t}.}
\quad & \sum_{i=1}^{N} \beta_i=1 ,\cr
 \end{align}
where $0<\alpha_0<1$, $\lambda_i$, and $\xi_i$ are constants.

Comment: It seems to fall into the realm of nonlinear programming.  You can check out some solution methods here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonlinear_programming

Comment: Use Lagrange multipliers and note the symmetry in the $\beta_i$'s.